# "Object reference not set" error when creating an NServiceBus bus

Tags: nservicebus

I'm having problems creating my bus. When I remove the last assembly from the collection being passed into the With() function ("MyAssembly.LetterProcessor") it does not break in this section, though it does break later. The error message is only "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". There is no inner exception.

I'm using NSB 3.2.0.0.

```
    NServiceBus.SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure);

    var assemblies = new List<Assembly> { Assembly.Load("NServiceBus"), Assembly.Load("NServiceBus.Core"), Assembly.Load("MyAssembly.LetterProcessor") };
    var cfg = NServiceBus.Configure.With(assemblies);

    cfg = cfg.DefineEndpointName("MyAssembly.letterprocessor");
    cfg = cfg.DefaultBuilder();
    cfg = cfg.DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null &&
                                      (
                                          t.Namespace.Equals("MyAssembly.LetterProcessor.NSB.BatchSaga")
                                          || t.Namespace.Equals("MyAssembly.LetterProcessor.NSB.FileSaga")
                                      )
        );
    cfg = cfg.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFault();
    cfg = cfg.Log4Net();
    cfg = cfg.StructureMapBuilder();
    cfg = cfg.XmlSerializer();
    cfg = cfg.MsmqTransport();
    cfg = cfg.IsTransactional(true);
    cfg = cfg.IsolationLevel(System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
    cfg = cfg.Sagas();
    cfg = cfg.NHibernateSagaPersister();
    var cfgu = cfg.UnicastBus();
    cfgu = cfgu.LoadMessageHandlers();
    var sb = cfgu.CreateBus();  // <-- breaks here.
    var bus = sb.Start();
```

... and the stack trace:

```
    at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder.EmitValue(BinaryWriter writer, Type type, Object value)
    at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder.InitCustomAttributeBuilder(ConstructorInfo con, Object[] constructorArgs, PropertyInfo[] namedProperties, Object[] propertyValues, FieldInfo[] namedFields, Object[] fieldValues)
    at System.Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder..ctor(ConstructorInfo con, Object[] constructorArgs, PropertyInfo[] namedProperties, Object[] propertyValues)
    at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.BuildCustomAttribute(Object customAttribute)
    at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.AddCustomAttributeToProperty(Object customAttribute, PropertyBuilder propBuilder)
    at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.CreateTypeFrom(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.GenerateImplementationFor(Type interfaceType, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.InitType(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.InitType(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.InitType(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 types)
    at NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.Config.MessageTypesInitializer.Run()
    at NServiceBus.Configure.<Initialize>b__d(IWantToRunWhenConfigurationIsComplete o)
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
    at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize()
    at NServiceBus.Configure.CreateBus()
    at MyAssembly.LetterProcessor.Service.Tests.Tests.EndpointInit() in C:\svn\MyAssembly\LetterProcessor\trunk\src\MyAssembly.LetterProcessor.Service.Tests\Tests.cs:line 72>
```

Comment: Dial up the logging level of your endpoint to DEBUG so that you can see which message type it was working on when it blew up.

Comment: Do you have a [obsolete] attribute (or any other attribute) on any of your messages?  https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/353

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been found. It was due to my mixing the Handler classes within the same namespace as the IMessage implementations.
Two solutions are possible: (1) I could separate the messages and the handlers into different namespaces/assemblies, or (2) I can specify that DefiningMessagesAs function filter by IMessage.

The second option looks like this:

```
    var bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With(assemblies)
       .DefineEndpointName("myApp.letterprocessor")
       .DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMessage))) // <-- fixes my problem
       ... etc
```